# how to deal with large map output in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am new in hadoop and i'm working with 3 node in a cluster(each of them has 2GB RAM).
the input file is small(5 MB) but map output is very large(about 6 GB).

in the map phase my memory becomes full and the tasks run very slowly.
what's its reason?

Can anyone helps me how to make my program faster?

Comment: 1st check for the amount of mappers per tasktracker: if there accumulated ram for the map tasks per node grows over (80% of) the physical ram, the machines start swapping and that will kill any vm performance. if there is no swapping, you will just have to wait until the mappers managed all the data (spills) ..

Answer (score 0):

Use a NLineInputFormat , where N refers to the number of lines of input each mapper will receive. This way, you have more splits created , there by forcing smaller input data to each mapper task.  If not, the entire 5 MB will go into one Map task.

Answer (score 0):

Size of map output by itself does not cause memory problem, since mapper can work in "streaming" mode. It consume records, process them and write to output. Hadoop will store some amount of data in memory and then spill it to disc. 
So you problems can be caused by one of the two: 
a) Your mapper algorithm somehow accumulate data during processing. 
b) Cumulative memory given to your mappers is less then RAM of the Nodes. Then OS start swapping and your performance can fell orders of magnitude.

Case b is more likely since 2 GB is actually too little for usual hadoop configuration. If you going to work on it - I would suggest to configure 1, maximum 2 mapper slots per node.